Azure QueueTrigger Function w/CosmosDB Output Binding Failing
I have a queue trigger Azure function (included below) that reads from and writes to a CosmosDB. I know that the function itself is working, as I do see some records being written to the database. But I am seeing a LOT of errors and many queued items end up in the poison queue. Looking at the items there, the format is correct and there is no reason to believe that the transactions are failing because the data is malformed.
The queue may contain upwards of 40k messages. With each of these messages being pushed to the database individually, is it possible my problem lies in how I establish a connection to the database (i.e. in the class constructor?) ... I'm kind of grasping at straws.
Watching the realtime log output, I see that it runs successfully for a while and then something happens. See the snippet from the logs below the code. It's as if the function is scaled out beyond the database's capacity to handle and begins timing out or something. Unfortunately, I'm pretty new at CosmosDB and working in queues, in general, so I'm not sure where to look and I can't seem to find an existing solution here on StackOverflow that addresses my particular situation.
namespace MatterFunctions
{
    public class CosmosDBQueueTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CosmosDBQueueTrigger> _logger;
        private string _endpointUri;
        private string _privateKey;
        private CosmosClient _client;

        public CosmosDBQueueTrigger(ILogger<CosmosDBQueueTrigger> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            _endpointUri = "****************/";
            _privateKey = "*******************";

            _client = new CosmosClient(_endpointUri, _privateKey);
        }

        [Function(nameof(CosmosDBQueueTrigger))]
        public async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("processed-records", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem,
        ILogger log)
        {

            // Parse the message from the queue
            var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClientMatterDTO>(myQueueItem);

            message!.firmId = "******";
            message.id = $"{message.ClientNumber}.{message.MatterNumber}";

            Database database = await _client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
                id: "ClientDB");

            Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
                id: "matters",
                partitionKeyPath: "/firmId",
                throughput: 400
            );

            var itemCount = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<ClientMatterDTO>(true)
                .Count(item => item.id == $"{message.ClientNumber}.{message.MatterNumber}");

            if (itemCount == 0)
            {
                await container.CreateItemAsync(
                    item: message,
                    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("qslwm")
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the log output containing some successful executions, and then the failures that appear after 20-30 seconds:
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=d39ea17e-7dca-485d-8c48-eafcbd61a65d)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: e480ad92-82a9-465d-ada6-0cb70ea7b5bc, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=db067251-686c-48f2-9523-1c76e72ffe95)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: ec0942a3-4c5e-4b28-b002-e2d5d4f08f5c, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=34d2562b-6164-4c23-be2b-fcb227069861)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: f6771598-aea3-41bf-b18f-4703564ca85a, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=0ad87c71-77ea-4145-99c4-ad3227c136bd)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: 13ff4bf5-4531-4276-930d-40ee6348c6f7, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=e9fa5bcf-f848-4dcb-9c85-e60d54d338bd)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: 4d4bdeaa-ce61-4b31-9412-852e3e262951, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=be650680-1612-47db-b1a9-0dfe6ea6c820)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: 4f1278c0-40bc-4f34-bc62-fed17e8a7a8d, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=03e6ded5-50ea-4d7c-b76b-2a3d021662fd)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: 524be9ea-ca23-4eee-afd5-c3642ba39c6c, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'processed-records'.', Id=f67753c0-7139-44be-9344-2dfc6b0f4583)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Trigger Details: MessageId: 55c55570-a60c-4832-bac4-9ea4a22923b6, DequeueCount: 4, InsertedOn: 2024-04-18T17:23:36.000+00:00
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=36cc6a91-128a-4022-b534-60d4b87f1971, Duration=4715ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=5c6902ea-09f4-4cbe-ae1d-ef3a71889799, Duration=4714ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=f288ec25-242a-4bf6-a108-e76c4c340a54, Duration=4713ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=e0110841-8e94-4152-9e35-a424cded1e35, Duration=4715ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=d6bb7bbb-1c52-4a3c-a201-20801438b7eb, Duration=4736ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=962edf9b-0cfd-4a81-a5bd-ad8f4f5f38f5, Duration=4738ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:09Z   [Error]   Function 'CosmosDBQueueTrigger', Invocation id '43ed6607-6ae0-4425-a014-4c6ff2437861': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
2024-04-18T20:30:09Z   [Error]   Function 'CosmosDBQueueTrigger', Invocation id 'af11707b-5495-455b-8a5e-06d4b41a0584': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
2024-04-18T20:30:09Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Failed, Id=af11707b-5495-455b-8a5e-06d4b41a0584, Duration=1195ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:09Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.CosmosDBQueueTrigger' (Failed, Id=43ed6607-6ae0-4425-a014-4c6ff2437861, Duration=1195ms)
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Stopping JobHost
2024-04-18T20:30:08Z   [Information]   Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.Listeners.QueueListener' for function 'CosmosDBQueueTrigger'
2024-04-18T20:30:11Z   [Information]   Task hub worker stopped. IsGracefulStop: False. Latency: 00:00:02.4124437. Extension GUID d418edb2-0c02-447e-912a-8fa1cc269c87. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: MatterFunctions. AppName: MatterFunctions. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.9.6. SequenceNumber: 4.
2024-04-18T20:30:11Z   [Information]   Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskListener' for function 'ProcessBatch'
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopping JobHost
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.Listeners.QueueListener' for function 'CosmosDBQueueTrigger'
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskListener' for function 'OrchestratorFunction'
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskListener' for function 'OrchestratorFunction'
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskListener' for function 'ProcessBatch'
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopping task hub worker. IsGracefulStop: False. Extension GUID 2c961204-449f-450c-8218-271df7ccf20e. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: MatterFunctions. AppName: MatterFunctions. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.9.6. SequenceNumber: 3.
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Task hub worker stopped. IsGracefulStop: False. Latency: 00:00:00.1383927. Extension GUID 2c961204-449f-450c-8218-271df7ccf20e. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: MatterFunctions. AppName: MatterFunctions. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.9.6. SequenceNumber: 4.
2024-04-18T20:30:16Z   [Information]   Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskListener' for function 'ProcessBatch'

I'm having trouble finding a log containing more detailed information about this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

You might be exhausting your RU/second allocation. But also: why are you attempting to create a database and collection with every single message-invocation? This will be a major issue, as these are management-plane transactions with a much lower transaction-rate capacity; this db/container creation should be done once (and not in your queue handler). Regarding RU in general: 400/second is fairly low, especially if you have 40,000 messages waiting in a queue - there's a very good chance you're being throttled when writing to Cosmos DB. With > 1 physical partition, RU is divided across them.

There might be details on the exception table in Application Insights. Normally that's where the Exceptions go.
As far as the code goes:

Please do not do CreateXXXXIfNotExists for each execution. This is part of the Best Practices: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/best-practice-dotnet
Instead of doing a Count query, see if either:

Doing a ReadItemAsync and catching a CosmosException with 404 status code is possible (assuming you know the id and partition key)
You can just do the Create and catch CosmosException with StatusCode 409 (Conflict), that would mean the document already existed.




or, if there was a TryGetItem API there would be no need to have a "and catching a CosmosException with 404 status code" proviso ;)

I see what you did there :D

lol - here's hoping whining in https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/4394 pays off over time (or maybe I need to make a PR and be done with it). I stare at ugly try/catches and/or overly complex ReadItemStreamAsync way too often for my liking... So yes, this is README driven development at tis finest -  SO answers can then boil down to "what you want to do here is a TryReadItem instead of a query" :D aka "If you're explaining, you're losing" :P (By the way, I've learned so much from following/stalking your answers here on SO, thanks!)
